# AWS ec2 laravel copy folder error 'App\Serviceprovider' not found

Tags: laravel, api, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a laravel project on AWS EC2. The project works fine. This is a project which I have used as an API backend for some apps.

The project is named api_dev_f_16. When I try to access the project, it returns the data as expected. I wanted to experiment something in this project so I decided to make a copy of the project and play with it. I used the below code to copy the folder

```
cp -rp api_dev_f_16 api_dev_f_17
```

This successfully clones the laravel project folder. When I try to access the cloned project through API, I get the below error

```
<h1 class="break-long-words exception-message">Class 'App\Serviceproviders' not found</h1>
```

I zipped the cloned project and downloaded to my local windows machine and deployed it to my local apache/php environment. This seems to work fine here too.

The original project works on AWS EC2 but the clone does not work. The clone also works on local windows machine.

I am guessing this could be related to some permission issues. However, I assume that -rp would also clone the user permissions right?

Can someone please give me a clue on what I could be doing wrong here?

Regards
Syed

Comment: it's odd that it would work locally but do try running `composer dump-autoload` in the cloned project in case the autoloader cached other path names

Comment: Thanks, my friend, you are a lifesaver. It took me a whole day and night and I could not figure it out. just ran the composer dump-autoload and it worked like a charm